# set webhook for telegram bot on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, pythonanywhere, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to run telegram bot via webhook. My python and flask version are 3.5. telebot library.

My code is:

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
import telebot

import requests
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

API_TOKEN = '***'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
```

this is for getting my ip:

```
res=requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/ip')
s=str(res.text)
s=s.split('\n')[0]

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = '/home/w/webhook_cert.pem'
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = '/home/w//webhook_pkey.pem'


bot.set_webhook(url="https://myacc.pythonanywhere.com", certificate=open('/home/adr/webhook_pkey.pem'))

WEBHOOK_HOST =s
#WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://myacc.pythonanywhere.com/'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 443
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://{}:{}".format(WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (API_TOKEN)
#updates = bot.get_updates()
```

Process webhook calls:

```
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return 'Hello flask'
    else:
        flask.abort(403)
```

It's not working and I get no error in log. How to make telegram bot works on pythonanywhere via webhook?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message,):                                                                                                                        
               bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hi ')

Comment: Are you using a free account?   If so, the library you're using might not be using the correct proxy settings to talk to Telegram.  I don't know how you would set that up using telebot, but there's a tutorial for telepot which has the appropriate code for that library: https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/148/

Comment: @Giles Thomas no , i am using payed account

Comment: Have you set it up on the "Web" tab on PythonAnywhere?  Or are you running it in a console?   BTW I don't think you should be specifying the certificate in the `set_webhook` call.

Comment: @ Giles Thomas   i set it up on web tab

Comment: Also interested. @egorkh did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure, You've installed telpot to the correct python version. you can do it by opening a new Bush console and type

   ```
   pip3.9 install telpot
   ```
2. Then import all necessary modules to test the webhook is working.

   ```
   from flask import Flask, request
    import telepot
    import urllib3
   ```
3. Then the proxy server, **Copy this code** without changing anything

   ```
   proxy_url = "http://proxy.server:3128"
    telepot.api._pools = {
        'default': urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=3, maxsize=10, retries=False, timeout=30),
    }
    telepot.api._onetime_pool_spec = (urllib3.ProxyManager, dict(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=1, maxsize=1, retries=False, timeout=30))
   ```

4. Then you have to enter your pythonanywhere server URL. To find it. Click on Web.

[image: If you can't find it it's easy to get. https://<your_username>.pythonanywhere.com/]

5. Replace this code with your *pythonanywhere Server URL*, Your *Bot API* and a *Random Number*. (You can type whatever random number you want. This is for security purposes)

   ```
   secret = "A_SECRET_NUMBER(Random Number)"
    bot = telepot.Bot('YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN')
    bot.setWebhook("https://YOUR_PYTHONANYWHERE_USERNAME.pythonanywhere.com/{}".format(secret), max_connections=1)
   ```
6. Now copy this code without making any changes. In this code, we are doing capturing the message sent by the user and sending it back to use again. You can do whatever you want.

   ```
   app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/{}'.format(secret), methods=["POST"])
    def telegram_webhook():
        update = request.get_json()
        if "message" in update:
            chat_id = update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
            if "text" in update["message"]:
                text = update["message"]["text"]
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "From the web: you said '{}'".format(text))
            else:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "From the web: sorry, I didn't understand that kind of message")
        return "OK"
   ```

   FULL CODE:

   ```
    from flask import Flask, request
    import telepot
    import urllib3

    proxy_url = "http://proxy.server:3128"
    telepot.api._pools = {
        'default': urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=3, maxsize=10, retries=False, timeout=30),
    }
    telepot.api._onetime_pool_spec = (urllib3.ProxyManager, dict(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=1, maxsize=1, retries=False, timeout=30))

    secret = "A_SECRET_NUMBER"
    bot = telepot.Bot('YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN')
    bot.setWebhook("https://YOUR_PYTHONANYWHERE_USERNAME.pythonanywhere.com/{}".format(secret), max_connections=1)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/{}'.format(secret), methods=["POST"])
    def telegram_webhook():
        update = request.get_json()
        if "message" in update:
            chat_id = update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
            if "text" in update["message"]:
                text = update["message"]["text"]
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "From the web: you said '{}'".format(text))
            else:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "From the web: sorry, I didn't understand that kind of message")
        return "OK"
   ```

Comment: hi there im trygin to replicate your code and i have a question, is it necesary to purchase a paid account?

Comment: No. It's not necessary. But in a free account, you can only create 1 web app.